# I want to integrate a laravel broadcast to update an html attribute in realtime

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher

HTML FOR PROGRESS BAR

```
<div class="ui fluid inverted segment" id="app">
    <div class="ui small header">ONGOING GRANT ANALYSIS </div>
    <div class="ui indicating big progress" id="grantprogress" :data-total="total" :data-value="value" >
        <div class="bar">
            <div class="progress" ></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS TO ACTIVATE IT

```
$('#grantprogress').progress();
```

VUEJS TO LISTEN TO CHANNEL

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    created(){
        Echo.channel('progress-bar-socket')
        .listen('ProgressUpdaterEvent', (e) => {
            this.value = e["update"];
        console.log(e["update"]);
        });
    },
    data: {
        total: 1500000,
        value: e["update"]
    }
});
```

I have a Laravel event that is sent when something happens on my website and it updates with some record counts from my database.I update the progress bar with the record counts in realtime. I can get the record counts in my console but binding it as an attribute to the html element of the progress bar is giving me issues.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html

Comment: I really don't understand as a newbie...i will really appreciate it if you can point me in the right direction and tell me what i am doing wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: What data is in the event? What exactly do you want to update?

Comment: I want to update this html attribute :data-value="value" in realtime with that data i get from pusher in my console log which is named update. I get the data in real time in the browser console i just dont know how to bind it in real time to that attribute

Comment: Does the answer below solve your issue or are you still needing help to set the attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:data-value="value"` is basically saying that the attribute `data-value` should be set to whatever `value` is in your `data` object.

To update the property `value` you just need to do

```
this.value = 'the new value of the property';
```

i.e.

```
created() {
    Echo.channel('progress-bar-socket')
        .listen('ProgressUpdaterEvent', (e) => {
            this.value = e["update"];
        });
},
```

I would recommend you have a look at [The series of tutorials](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step)

---

The value for the progress bar won't automatically update when the attribute changes. Looking at the [docs](https://fomantic-ui.com/modules/progress.html#/usage), to update the value you can use:

```
 $('#grantprogress').progress('set progress', this.value);
```

So, you can either set up a water for `value` or just put this directly your listener callback:

```
Echo.channel('progress-bar-socket')
.listen('ProgressUpdaterEvent', e => {
    $('#grantprogress').progress('set progress', e.update);
});
```

Comment: const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    created(){
        Echo.channel('progress-bar-socket')
        .listen('ProgressUpdaterEvent', (e) => {
            this.value = e["update"];
        console.log(e["update"]);
        });
    },
    data: {
        total: 1500000,
        value: 0
    }
});
no changes

Comment: @daqustae The attribute doesn't update at all? Or the progress bar doesn't update? If it's the progress bar, please can you tell me what library you're using to generate it.

Comment: whenever i input a value in the value option of the data section the attribute and progress bar updates on page reload. but it does not update in realtime using the update from pusher whereas it logs to console

Comment: @daqustae Please can you update your question and add the code your using to initialise the progress bar.

Comment: wow...it is marvelous. Can I set the total option besides the this.value too?

Comment: @daqustae Sorry, I'd forget to link to the docs in my answer. I've added it in now (https://fomantic-ui.com/modules/progress.html#/usage). It looks like you would just need to do `$('#grantprogress').progress('set total', 1500000)`. Has this answered your question?

Comment: You are a life saver, wish i could buy you lunch. Thanks so so so much